# Using same variable name in separate group variable in Ansible inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using the same name of the variables within separate variable groups within an inventory file.

For example:

```
###hosts file####
[GROUP1]
var1  127.0.0.1
var2  127.0.0.1
[GROUP2]
var1  127.1.0.1
var2  127.1.0.1
```

I would like know to apply my playbook on the var1 of GROUP2. how can I do it ?
For example:

```
- hosts: GROUP2.var1
  become: root
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the playbook on 1st host of 2nd group you can use:

```
- hosts: {{groups.GROUP2[0]}}
  become: root
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: user
```

Just one thing is var1 also a host or variable define for that host ? The above `{{groups.group2[0]}}` will refer to host not variable. If you want to use that variable in any task then use `{{ hostvars[groups['GROUP2'][0]].var1 }}`.

Also in the host file right way to define vars and host would be first host and then vars.

```
[GROUP1]
127.0.0.1 var1=something
127.0.0.1 var2=something2
......
```